# Prove: for any $n$, $1+10^4+...+10^{4n}$ is a composite number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, integers

I saw the first three terms: $1$, $10000$, $100000000$. I thought about proving by induction, so I did:

**Base case:** At $n>0$, [$10001$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10%5E4%2B1%20prime%20factorization) is composite. Note that at $n=0$, we get $1$ which is not composite. And at $n<0$, we get decimals which are against composite number [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_number). So, $n$ cannot be $\le 0$.

**Hypothesis:** Let it be true for $k$, such that $m = 1+10^4+...+10^{4k}$ is a composite number.

**Proof:** Add $10^{4(k+1)}$ to $m$. So, m becomes $1+10^4+...+10^{4k}+10^{4k+4}$ which is a composite number + composite number. However, as I can trivially infer from $9+4=13$, a composite number + composite number is not always another composite.

**Question:** How to solve this question? Hints for getting started?

**UPDATE:**

So, as @Michael told me, this is a geometric series. So, using $\frac{a(1-r^m)}{1-r}$, so letting $a=1, r = 10^4$, I got: $$\frac{1*(1-(10^{4})^{n+1})}{1-10^4} \implies \frac{10^{4n+4}-1}{9999}$$ How to proceed further?

Comment: Can you see the pattern in the divisors?

Comment: @MichaelBurr  I cannot see any pattern.

Comment: This is also a geometric series, can you use that?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Ah! I failed to see that! I'm trying, let me see if I can do that using $\frac{a(1-r^m)}{1-r}$

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I've looked at the prime factorization of $\frac{10000^{\,p}-1}{9999}$ for $p=2, 3, 5, 7, 11$ and no nice pattern seems to emerge. The most pattern-like is 9901, 9091, 909091 for $p=3,5,7$, but that's not really systematic and breaks for $p=11$ anyway.

Comment: It is easy to see that the sum is composite when $n+1$ is composite, so you only need to prove it when $n+1$ is prime. Induction doesn't seem to be helpful here (or at least not directly), and there's no common factor -- indeed, no factor repeats in common for any two of $n+1\in\{2,3,5,7,11\}$. All in all, it looks hard.

Comment: @Gaurang Tandon: It should be $\frac{10^{4n+4}-1}{9999}$ instead of $\frac{10^{4n}-1}{9999}$.

Comment: @mathlove Thank you for noting this! I am making corrections.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We write the number as

$$\frac{10^{4m}-1}{10^4-1},$$

where $m \geqslant 2$.

**Case 1:** $m$ even. Write $m = 2r$, then our number is

$$\frac{10^{8r}-1}{10^4-1} = \frac{10^{4r}-1}{10^4-1}\cdot (10^{4r}+1).$$

If $r = 1$, then it is easy to check that $10^4+1$ is composite, and for $r > 1$ we note that $\frac{10^{4r}-1}{10^4-1} > 1$, which shows our number is composite.

**Case 2:** $m$ odd. Write

$$\frac{10^{4m}-1}{10^4-1} = \frac{10^{2m}+1}{101}\cdot \frac{10^m+1}{11}\cdot\frac{10^m-1}{9}.$$

Since $m$ is odd, we have $10^{2m} \equiv (-1)^m \equiv -1\pmod{101}$, and $10^m \equiv (-1)^m \equiv -1\pmod {11}$, so all factors are integers. Since $m > 1$, all three factors are $> 1$.

Answer (score 6):

$$10^{4n}-1=(10^{2n}-1)(10^{2n}+1)=(10^n-1)(10^n+1)(10^{2n}+1)$$
so it has factors much larger than $9999$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I have got $10^{4n}+1$ in question, and there's no $-1$ in the expression anywhere. So, I can't relate what you are trying to explain. Please do the needful. Thanks!

Comment: Your last line has $\frac{10^{4n}-1}{9999}$ and my answer shows the numerator has large factors, so the original sum has factors left after dividing by 9999.

Comment: Oh.yes! Got it!

Comment: I almost wrote a similar answer, but refrained. That's becuase, agreed, this has larger factors than 9999, but what if that factor is prime.

Comment: There are two factors which are larger than 9999 so long as $n\geq4$.  If they are both prime, there are two prime factors that remain after division by 9999.